# rails4 with turbolinks, js function invoking options for user triggered events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

In a rails4 app with turbolinks is there any different between these 2 solutions?

For me it seems to be the same since the event is triggered by the user. Or did I miss something?

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {
  $('.new-task-submit').on('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var localMoment = moment($('.new-task-deadline').val());
    $('.new-task-deadline').val(localMoment.toISOString());
    $('#newtask').submit();
  });
});

$(document).on("'click', '.new-task-submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var localMoment = moment($('.new-task-deadline').val());
  $('.new-task-deadline').val(localMoment.toISOString());
  $('#newtask').submit();
});
```

Comment: It is definitely possible to do the same thing in different ways. What you need to decide is which is more appropriate, makes sense and is most readable.

Comment: Antiokus, can you tell me how to decide which one is appropriate and if there any technical differences I should be aware of?

Comment: well first thing I notice is that the first implementation is triggered `.on("page:change")` - where as the second implementation does not. So you need to decide if that is relevant for you. Personally I would go with the first one as it's a little more readable than the second. But up to you.

Comment: Antiokus, could you tell me an example where these 2 codes work differently? I mean I know there is the page:change, but with document binded user triggered events it seems to be the same for me.

Comment: I'm not really a jQuery expert, but there may be an edge case where one doesn't behave exactly like the other. For that, I suggest you read up on the triggers and their behaviours. Choose the one that most suits your needs.